# Private Network Setup

Tags: private-network

Can stellar network be deployed locally as private network? If yes please can you let me know the tutorial. Also does stellar use smart contracts?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Stellar private network locally using docker-compose. The instructions for doing that can be found here:

https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/horizon/docker#running-stellar-with-docker-compose